# VBA autofilter criteria's

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

In column I have different type of text, there're zeros, blanks, numbers, dashes. Through VBA autofilter I want to choose all zeros, blanks and dashes and also numbers < 1000 (or numbers that have less than four character). My code is below.

How I can modify or correct it to get correct autofilter?

```
.Autofilter 14, 
    Array:=(
        Chr(32), Chr(45), Chr(10), Chr(13), CHr(150), Chr(175), Chr(151), Chr(48),
        "<1000"
    ),
    Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Comment: If you remove `"<1000"` from your array it will work. Maybe work in batches? First filter on exact values through array and later one lower than 1000. Join the two ranges if need be

Comment: I want to filter columns simultaneously, that means in result should be values equal dashes, zeros, blanks and also values less than 1000. For example, 
Column(1111, 1111, 0, -, ,1111, 66) Result(0,-, , 66)